# Automator for Vista

Tags: windows-vista, automation, software-rec, automator, mouse-click

Is a there a similar program for Vista like the Mac application Automator?

Specifically I'm looking for a Vista app that can control timed clicks.  For example, in Automator, I can specify which pixel and how often to click, or a series of click in different places.  I'm not looking for an "intelligent clicker", just a purely GUI programmed clicker. Also I need it do work and record the keyboard.  From reading other SU posts I can see that the command prompt doesn't have an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

you may want to try out autohotkey (open source, free as in freedom & in beer) http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey, AutoIt or Sikuli are good choices. For automating clicking and form filling *inside the browser*, try the free iMacros for IE/Firefox/Chrome browser addons.